# Add html element (or angular component) on call of a function, in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button, click

I have a component, that has a button. The button is connected to a function in the `.ts` file. Now, I want the function to add an HTML element or maybe un-hide it on the click of the button. I basically just want an html `<div>` element to become visible on the screen (with some dynamic data).

Following is what the button in the `component.html` file looks like:

```
<button mat-button (click)="getInfo()" mat- cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
```

Following is what the `getInfo()` function in the `component.ts` file currently looks like:

```
getInfo(){
    console.log("Button clicked");
}
```

So my objective is, on the click of the button, some element appears on the screen or maybe another angular component appears. Some advice on how to achieve that would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I am very new to front-end development, but I did try reading-up and searching on Stack-overflow and nothing comprehensive came up.

Comment: I think you can use *ngIf directive in .html and in .ts file create some boolean variable. After that in your method change this boolean variable to true - than element in html will appear.

Comment: So you want to add dynamically an html element/angular component or this will be hidden and you want to show it up?

Comment: @tufonas I actually want the element to be added dynamically, but if it's not possible, then I can work with un-hiding the element.

Comment: @MateuszŚcigała Thanks for the reply, I'll try that out!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply adding a boolean in your component.

`showEl = false;`

and on clicking button,

```
getinfo() {
   this.showEl = !this.showEl;
}
```

And in template, you can use `*ngIf` to show/hide the content.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button (click)="isShowInfo = !isShowInfo">Toggle me</button>

<div *ngIf="isShowInfo">
   <p>Here is my info</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hashtag of angular to make your code simpler.

```
<button (click)="testId.style.visibility = 'visible'">Unhide me</button>

<div style="visibility: hidden;" #testId>
   i am hidden
</div>
```

If you want to unhide it from the typescript you have to use `@ViewChild` to watch the hidden element and when you call one method on click you will set the visibility to visible

Comment: avoid using "style" tag. avoid using "visibility: hidden". avoid using template-var. Use *ngIf as much as possible.

Comment: Agreed with @Random